# How to draw a real-time line graph with a stream of values?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

If I have a stream of values, how can I draw a line chart in real-time based on those values?

Comment: Have you tried building your chart inside the builder function of a StreamBuilder widget?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this will help but I have just added a plugin to Flutter that may do what you need, or if not at least give you some ideas. You can find it [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/oscilloscope)

And in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/magnatronus/acc51a60b5d707b44d6859022d6b7a14) I have modified the example code to read the data from the device sensor stream (in real-time)  which it then graphs out.

Comment: Thanks! If I were  to stream it from a CSV, how would I go about updating the dataset?

Comment: Trying to use your example, but my dataset contains values in the range of 10000s. I changed the yAxisMax and yAxisMin, but the values aren't showing.

Comment: @stack thanks for the feedback, I have modified the package (0.0.3) so this should now work correctly without the need to divide by 10000

Comment: Great. Also, how do I give the stream a break? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I recommand [mp_chart](https://github.com/SunPointed/MPFlutterChart) which is basically the dart version of (the great) MPAndroidChart.

Comment: mp_chart is not null-safe and seems to be no longer supported. =(

Answer (score 1):

You can use fl_chart is very awesome

https://github.com/imaNNeo/fl_chart/issues/1118